# Should I create a separate user table for different web products within the same platform?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

We have a web product for young professional that gives them the possibility to create their page to show their professional identity.
So a table `users` that has both information about the user (email, password, name) including their credentials and information about their page (premium or not, page address, theme)

Now we want to offer the possibility for recruiters to signup to our platform to browse through candidates. A recruiter can also be a user with a page but does not have to.

Now our two approaches:

A/ Create a table `recruiters` with name and credentials of the recruiter and a column `user_id` to connect with the `ID` of the table `users` if they have created a site.

- Benefits : The product can be easily developed separately, by two different teams.
- Inconvenient : Duplicates of the name and credentials if the recruiter is also a user.
  We would need to either update both credential when one is updated or to let them have two different email/password combination, one for their user account, one for their recruiter account.

Database structure:

```
users
ID name email password group_id premium theme page_address

recruiters
ID name email password company_id user_id
```

B/ Add the recruiters to the `users` table with a different `group_id` and move all the information about the users page in another table (premium or not, page address, theme). We would also have a third table for the recruiter containing any information specific to them.

- Benefits : One table with all the credentials.
- Inconvenient : If we reach millions of users, any query among recruiters will have to take a tiny subset among a huge table. Also : lots of join to get the site information for every user.

Database structure:

```
users
ID name email password group_id

pages
user_id premium theme page_address

recruiters
user_id company_id
```

C/ Any other solution?

Thank you for your inputs!

Tristan

Comment: Option B seems fine to me. Even if you get millions of users, your database should handle that fine with the right indexes. You should still get 1-2ms query times. If for some reason it did become an issue, you could move inactive/deleted users to a historical table to keep the table down to only active users. You can create a view to do the common joins for you, which would simplify the queries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, how about database sharding? If we have separates databases that will become a problem.

Comment: Thinking about sharding now might be a little pre-mature. If your site grows to the point where you have 10's of millions of users, sharding might not be your biggest problem. At this point I would consider it a pre-mature optimization. But if you do get there, you're right, it can be a lot of work to maintain databases across servers. You can always check out something like Mongo that has sharding built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relational database architecture is not an exact science, but you can relay on a few common guidelines to make good decisions. In the first option you present, it can be easily identified that there's a situation of column duplication. Few of your columns have the exact same meaning on a conceptual point of view. The `password` column is used to log on your website whether or not you're a recruiter. This wouldn't always be considered an issue, but it's a great hint that there should be a better relational pattern to design your data schema.

A great approach to resolve such concerns is to establish conceptual relations between objects. For instance :

- `Users` are or aren't `Recruiters` would be a `0..1 <-> 1`
  relationship or an *optional* [One to One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx#dvmscone_to_onerelationships)
- `Pages` belongs to a `Users` would be a `1 <-> 1` relationship or [One to One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx#dvmscone_to_onerelationships)
- `Recruiters` might have a `Pages` would be a `0..1 <-> 1` relationship or an *optional* [One to One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx#dvmscone_to_onerelationships)

This exercise helps you to understand how to list your entities and organize your *foreign keys*. This is a good first step that, in your situation, gives us three tables : `Users`, `Recruiters` and `Pages`. Notice how *foreign keys* for [One to One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx#dvmscone_to_onerelationships) relationships were placed in the mandatory `1` [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) tables.

[image]

Now to determine where to place your data columns and whether or not you should have new tables : an easy trick would be to write everything your [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) entity would have as such by targeting the most derivated entity you have.

[image]

This example is pretty obvious, but I still think it's answering your question and your doubt regarding a group entity and columns duplication.

[image]

At this point I realized I forgot to include the `Companies` entity that would be stated as such :

- `Companies` can have multiple `Recruiters` would be a `1..* <-> 1` relationship or a [One to Many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s9x13w7.aspx#dvmscone_to_manyrelationships)

[image]

Once again, keep in mind people might not always agree with this approach, but considering this small context; it was an easy train of thoughts. The answer you would have been looking for is : *Column's meaning duplication is a hint you should approach your data schema differently.* Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53edf/1/2).

If you have any questions or feel this is wrong feel free to comment!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Actually we went for the approach A eventually, the main reason being that they are two different products so we consider now 'Users' as 'Candidates' and have a separate table for the Recruiters. As time goes we will see if that was the right choice!